# iPhone auto sync photos with our application using AlAssetLibrary

Tags: iphone, image, synchronization, alasset, photolibrary

I have just started developing an application in which I want to auto sync all the images stored in user's photo library as assets.

I am able to get URL for images those are stored as assets.

```
e.g. assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000003&ext=JPG
```

Now, how do I copy this image in to document's directory of my application or how do I just display image stored in assets by getting that in `NSData` or in `UIImage`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate implementation

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    //obtaining saving path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_photo.png"];

    //extracting image from the picker and saving it
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: @RuchirAgile, as soon as you get the asset, copy it right away as @Jhaliya suggests.

Comment: I am not using ImagePickerController as using ImagePicker you can get only one image at a time. I want to sync/get all the photos on my app launch.